# COUNT(1) OVER () with Linq to Sql

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Can I do this with Linq to SQL?

```
select top 10 count(1) over(), * from product
```

Today I do 2 selects, one to count and another to select the page:

- `select count(1) from product`
- `select top 10 * from product`

The select with `count(1) over()` is much better since return total count together the page. I profile the queries and putting `count(1) over()` dont add any millisecond to original

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
ctx.Products.Take(10).Select(p => new {Total = ctx.Products.Count, Product = p})
```

Comment: You might need a `Take(10)` in there somewhere to get the same results as the OP's SQL